# Registering Micro Services on Kong and use of docker /k8s while deploying Kong artifacts

Tags: kong, kong-plugin, kong-ingress, konga, kongregate

We are migrating from one landscape to the other landscape

Both are AWS

Its a kind of lift and shift. While doing so what configurations to register Micro Services to Kong or deploying Kong artifacts or integrating the Kong with logging and monitoring services like Datadog need to be done?

Like for registering the microservices we need to creat yaml file with repository and the API endpoints in it and need to deploy it to K8S, correct?

Similarly what other configurations or steps need to be done considering its a lift and shift from one landscape to the other?

We need to register the micro services as services and the API endpoints in the service as routes

Other than this what other configurations need to be done? Thanks